# For positive real numbers $a, b, c$, maximise $(a-3)(b-2)(c-1)$ given $a+b+c=18$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For positive real numbers $a, b, c$, if $a + b + c = 18$, then max value of $(a-3)(b-2)(c-1) =$?

**My approach:-**

$a-3=x$

$b-2=y$

$c-1=z$

I get $x+y+z=12$ , and I need to find $\max(xyz)$.

So I applied AM-GM inequality here,

$\dfrac{x+y+z}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$,

which gives me the answer as $64$.

But the answer given in the book is $102$, and also it states that AM-GM cannot be applied here.  I don't understand why can't we apply it here, the only condition AM-GM requires is that we have positive real numbers, right, then what is the issue ?

Comment: Are $x$, $y$, and $z$ all positive, even if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are?

Comment: We approach $102 = (-3)(-2)(17)$ in the limit as $a \to 0, b \to 0, c \to 18$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, how did we get these limits? and so our answer would be max value tending to 102 ?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value of $102$ can be proven if we relax the constraints slightly, such that $a,b,c$ are all non-negative reals, instead of positive reals.

**Case $1$:** All $3$ terms are greater than or equal to zero.
By AM-GM,
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{(a-3)(b-2)(c-1)} & \leq \dfrac{a-3+b-2+c-1}{3} \\
& =4.
\end{align}
This gives us $(a-3)(b-2)(c-1) \leq 64.$

**Case $2$:**
Exactly $1$ term is less than or equal to zero. Clearly, $(a-3)(b-2)(c-1) \leq 0.$

**Case $3$:**
All $3$ terms are less than or equal to zero, which is impossible since this would imply $a+b+c \leq 6$.

**Case $4$:**
Exactly $2$ terms are less than or equal to zero. There are $3$ further sub-cases to consider:

**Sub-case $1$:**
$a-3 \leq 0, \ c-1 \leq 0.$
Then,
\begin{align}
(a-3)(b-2)(c-1) & =(3-a)(b-2)(1-c) \\
\end{align}
It is obvious that $3-a \leq 3, \ b-2 \leq 16, \ 1-c \leq 1 \Rightarrow (3-a)(b-2)(1-c) \leq 48. $

**Sub-case $2$:**
$b-2 \leq 0, \ c-1 \leq 0.$
Then,
\begin{align}
(a-3)(b-2)(c-1) & =(a-3)(2-b)(1-c) \\
\end{align}
We have: $a-3 \leq 15, \ 2-b \leq 2, \ 1-c \leq 1 \Rightarrow (a-3)(2-b)(1-c) \leq 30. $

**Sub-case $3$:**
$a-3 \leq 0, \ b-2 \leq 0.$
Then,
\begin{align}
(a-3)(b-2)(c-1) & =(3-a)(2-b)(c-1) \\
\end{align}
We have: $3-a \leq 3, \ 2-b \leq 2, \ c-1 \leq 17 \Rightarrow (3-a)(2-b)(c-1) \leq 102. $ In particular, this maximum value is achieved when $a=0,\ b=0,\ c=18.$